# Create copy of a database only schema

Tags: database, sql-server-2005

I am relativley new to MS SQL server. I need to create a test database from exisitng test data base with same schema and get the data from production and fill the newly created empty database. For this I was using generate scripts in SSMS. But now I need to do it on regular basis in a job. Please guide me how I can create empty databases automatically at a point of time.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a very hard time automating the generate scripts wizard. I would suggest using something like [Red-Gate's SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) ([or any alternative](http://bertrandaaron.wordpress.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/) that supports command-line). You can create a new, empty database, then script a compare/deploy using the command line from SQL Server Agent.

Another, more icky alternative, is to deploy your schema and modules to the `model` database. You can keep this in sync using SQL Compare (or alternatives), or just be diligent about deployment of schema/module changes, then when you create a new database it will automatically inherit the current state of your schema/modules. The problem with this approach (other than depending on you keeping `model` in sync) is that *all* new databases will inherit this schema, since [there currently is no way to have multiple models](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=322571).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered restoring backups?

Answer (score 0):

To add to Aaron's already good answer, I've been using [SQLDelta](http://sqldelta.com) for years - I think it's excellent.

(I have no connection to SqlDelta, other than being a very satisfied customer)